# Java Writing to a File Test Scores

Tags: java

I have to make a program that asks the user to enter several scores. Each score needs to be written to the file "scores.txt," but after I enter my 10 scores, the program doesn't do anything, and the scores are not being written to the file. Basically, I'm not sure how to use processFile to show the mean score. The final program should prompt the user for several scores, write the scores to a file, then open that file, calculate the mean, and display it. I have to use an exit condition, and if it is negative, it should assume the user is done entering data.

```
    public class MoreTestScores {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        writeToFile("scores.txt");
        processFile("scores.txt");
    }

    public static void writeToFile (String filename) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("scores.txt"));
        System.out.println("Please enter 10 scores.");
        System.out.println("You must hit enter after you enter each score.");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int score = 0;
        while (score <= 10) {
            int val = sc.nextInt();
            if (val < 0) break;
            outputWriter.write(val);
            score++;
        }
        outputWriter.flush();
        outputWriter.close();
    }

    public static void processFile (String filename) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        double sum = 0;
        double number;
        double average;
        double count = 0;
        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("scores.txt")));
        String line;
        while ((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
            number = Double.parseDouble(line);
            sum += number;
            count ++;
        }
        average = sum/count;
        System.out.println(average);
        inputReader.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `PrintWriter` instead in the `writeToFile()` (I have tested the code):

```
public static void writeToFile(String filename) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter outputWriter = new PrintWriter("scores.txt");
    System.out.println("Please enter 10 scores.");
    System.out.println("You must hit enter after you enter each score.");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int score = 0;
    while (score < 10) {
        int val = sc.nextInt();
        if (val < 0)
            break;
        outputWriter.println(val);
        score++;
    }
    outputWriter.flush();
    outputWriter.close();
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @SikkiNixx Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

2 problems I can see.

- You are trying  writing the `int` value. This method is meant to
  write a single charecter, not a integer.See [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write%28int%29) 
  So you need to write value as `String` in order to read back as `String`
- You are not writing each value in each line.But reading as individual lines

So please change the writing code inside `while` loop as below:

```
 outputWriter.write(String.valueOf(val));
 outputWriter.newLine();
```